# MySql and SQlite classes implementing interface

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite, interface

This shouldnt be hard to answer but I am so desperate and confused. I made interface for executing read query from database

```
interface IDatabase
{
    DataTable ExecuteReaderCommand(IDbCommand command);
    IDbCommand GetNewCommand();
}
```

Next, I created two different classes implemetnig above interface.

```
class MysqlDatabase : IDatabase
{
    public DataTable ExecuteReaderCommand(MySqlCommand command)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        // ... read db
        return dt;
    }

    public MySqlCommand GetNewCommand()
    {
        cnn.Open();
        return cnn.CreateCommand();
    }
}
```

And

```
class SQLiteDatabase : IDatabase
{
String dbConnection;
    SQLiteConnection cnn;

    public DataTable ExecuteReaderCommand(SQLiteCommand command)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        // ... read db
        return dt;
    }

    public SQLiteCommand GetNewCommand()
    {
        cnn.Open();
        return cnn.CreateCommand();
    }
}
```

But I am getting error that these classes dont implement IDatabase interface:

```
 MysqlDatabase does not implement interface member 'Database.GetNewCommand()'
 MysqlDatabase.GetNewCommand() cannot implement 'Database.GetNewCommand()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Data.IDbCommand'.

 SQLiteDatabase does not implement interface member Database.ExecuteReaderCommand(System.Data.IDbCommand)
 SQLiteDatabase does not implement interface member 'Database.GetNewCommand()'. SQLiteDatabase.GetNewCommand() cannot implement Database.GetNewCommand() because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Data.IDbCommand'.
```

When I look on the `SQLiteCommand` and `MySqlCommand` they both implements `IDbCommand`.

**How can I use these classes under common interface so I can easilly switch them?**

I am very thankful for any answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I look on the SQLiteCommand and MySqlCommand they both implements IDbCommand

No they don't. They claim they do, but they don't actually provide the right methods. Look at `IDatabase.GetNewCommand()`:

```
IDbCommand GetNewCommand();
```

and your implementation:

```
public MySqlCommand GetNewCommand()
{
    ... 
}
```

They've got different return types. Likewise your `ExecuteReaderCommand` method parameter is `IDbCommand` in `IDatabase`, but `MySqlCommand` in `MysqlDatabase`.

Options:

- Use explicit interface implementation for the "weakly typed" version, exposing the "strongly typed" versions on the concrete classes. This is what `SqlCommand` does in the .NET framework, for example.
- Make `IDatabase` generic in the type of command it creates and uses:

  ```
  public interface IDatabase<TCommand> where TCommand : IDbCommand
  {
      DataTable ExecuteReaderCommand(TCommand command);
      TCommand GetNewCommand();
  }
  ```

Comment: Option 1 is exactly what I wanted to do. Could you please point me in right direction how to do it? I need common interface for MysqLCommand and SQLiteCommand. I thought it is IDbCommand.